# Must refresh multiple times to load a webpage

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, firewall, macbook

I have to refresh my browser all the time. I'm using Chrome on my Macbook. It's only an issue on my Macbook. My iPhone and iPad work just fine.

The problem is when I enter a URL, sometimes the page loads fine, but most times the page won't load (keeps loading without anything happening), or it loads but only text is visible and not the pictures, OR the browser displays

> This site can’t be reached [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com) unexpectedly closed the connection.
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I have no clue what it could be... It has been going on for over a week now.

Is anybody having the same issue?

Sometimes it will give me the error of:

> "This site can’t be reached The connection was reset."

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like a networking issue, maybe bad ethernet cable/ends or interference with wifi or failing wifi chip. I would recommend running a network test between two devices on your network and look for dropped packets. You said you are using Chrome... does it do the same with another browser?

Comment: Indeed it does. Hmm. Not seeing any dropped packets. Tested with Ping. Then used Traceroute which showed a lot of *** indicating connection hangs. Not sure where to go from here. What are your thoughts, Alex?

Comment: On Windows, I would look into drivers at this point but only if ethernet vs wifi performed differently, mac would probably be the same strategy. Have you noticed any option performing any better than the other? If both performed the exact same, it would be a system or browser issue. (Two separate ip and mac addresses kind of rules out router issues tied to a single connection.

Comment: Turned off Avast Web Shield. Waiting to see if that was the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Just change your main DNS to 8.8.8.8 and alternative DNS to 8.8.4.4 , in the network adapter properties and then by going in the properties of Ipv4 internet protocol.

Thank me later :)

Comment: “Thank me later :)” For what? Generic advice about changing the DNS to Google’s servers? `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`? How do you know this is a DNS issue and not a general networking issue?